# The closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am reading through Chapter 2 of Rudin and working through a table of results he gives on page 33. I want to show that the set of all complex $z$ such that $|z| \leq 1$ is a perfect set.

I have already shown that the set is closed, so I just need to show that every point in the set is a limit point.

let $r > 0$ and let $D$ denote the given set, and let $z_{0}, w \in D$. Then I need to show that every neighbourhood of $z_{0}$ contains a point different to $z_{0}$ that is also in $D$.

So do I need to consider $B(z_{0},r) \cap D \neq \emptyset$? I don't know how to mathematically make the next bit of the argument. In words it seems obvious to me any disk centered around $z_{0}$ will contain another point in $D$, and in particular it can now contain the boundary point.

Maybe I can look at different cases of $r$? If $r \geq 1$ and $r < 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $z_0 \in \partial D$ consider $(1-\frac 1n)z_0$. If $|z_0| <1$ consider $z_0+\frac 1 n w$ (with $w \in D$ fixed).   For $n$ sufficiently large these points belong to $B(z_0,r) \cap D$.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. So just check i understand the argument is something like: Consider $r > 0$ let $D$ be as given. Then if $z_{0} \in \partial D$  $(1 - \frac{1}{n})z_{0}$ If $|z_{0}| < 1$ then the point $z_{0} + \frac{1}{n}w $ where $w \in D$ is fixed. Then for $n$ large enough both belong to $B(z_{0},r) \cap D$. ?

Comment: @learningmathematics Yes, that is correct.